# Docker Container vs Virtual Machine

Tags: windows, docker, kernel, containers

I am using docker desktop on windows 10. I downloaded an image for windows server core 1909.

then created two containers from the same image.

Docker run -it mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:1909 powershell.exe

when I ran sysinfo on both, it gave me different hostname for both OS.

how do I see that kernel is shared? because I see these are two different VMs which is no different than hyper-v VM of the core OS.

I though docker container is sharing a kernel but I don't see the same OS underneath?

any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Ok i got the answer also. There is concept of hyper-v isolation level for containers in windows. so if the host is not same version as of the container, you will get what you call hyper-v isolation which is essentially not a process isolation, its rather a virtual machine like traditional thing. no shared kernel.

True container concept which is actually shared kernel is only possible on windows server host and when used container version which is also same.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/deploy-containers/version-compatibility?tabs=windows-server-1909%2Cwindows-10-1809